# Efficient algorithm for maximum of a differentiable function

Tags: numerical-methods

Is there an efficient algorithm which can be used to find the global maximum of a differentiable function (of one variable) on a given interval?

Answer (score 3):

No, and there never will be (even though you did not define efficient).  Given any nice function, you can add a narrow and tall [bump function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) at an unknown point to create a new maximum. How can you prove that this is not the function you are trying to find the maximum of?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the derivative you can use any root-finding algorithm, whose efficiency will depend on the type of function you have and the algorithm you choose. If you don't have the derivative you may need to approximate it somehow, and the efficiency of that depends again on what kind of function you have.

For example, a concave function will have only one maximum and hence it can be easily found by binary search. However, even binary search is very slow and has linear convergence, whereas Newton-Raphson approximation (if the function has a second derivative that you can get or approximate) has quadratic convergence under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

For local maxima, you can use local methods to verify that you're at a maximum. However, you can't use local information to verify that you're at a global maximum. To get that requires extra information about the function. You need some condition that guarantees a single maximum or a known finite number of maxima that you can then find and compare.

If you give me an algorithm that finds global maxima, I can construct a differentiable function on which that algorithm fails (or at the very least becomes horribly inefficient).